# SQL Update using "where" value from another table?

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables, `table_a` and `table_b`. I want to get `user_id` from `table_a` and update a record in `table_b` for that `user_id`. Something like this:

```
Select * from table_a where user_id ="Ken"

if result is 22 

Update score = 1 where id = 22.
```

These queries work but I want to combine them in one. Can anyone please tell me what is the best way to do this?

Comment: What version of SQL are you using? mysql/oracle/sql server?  These different RDBMS will have different options.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this this should work,

```
UPDATE table_b
SET score=1
WHERE id = (select id from table_a where user_id ="Ken")
```

Answer (score 3):

```
UPDATE table_b SET score = 1
WHERE id IN (SELECT * FROM table_a WHERE user_id = "Ken")
```

Comment: Ah good catch pst. Might help if I reference the table being updated :)

Answer (score 1):

```
IF EXISTS (Select * from table_a where user_id ="Ken" )
If result=22
BEGIN
UPDATE table_a SET score = 1
END
```